# MathJax extension on Joomla HTML making parenthesis italic or emphasized text

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla3.0, mathjax

I am creating a [website](http://simpleai.it/it/style-your-website.html) on Joomla, I am using HTML to write an article. Because I needed to write Maths stuff, I googled a little bit how to use LaTex on HTML. I encountered this: https://github.com/widgetfactory/wf-mathjax

Which is a Joomla extension (written in PHP). I've installed it and then tried using standard mathematics stuff, such as $a = b + c$ and it worked! The issue though, is that now if I just type

```
<p>This text is (in parenthesis) but it doesn't work. </p>
```

Then instead of having "This text is in (parenthesis) but it doesn't work", I get:

"This text is *in parenthesis* but it doesn't work."

**How to reproduce my error:**

If you follow the link to my website, after the main image you'll see:

[image: mathjax]

where my HTML code is:

```
<h1>Header 1</h1>
<h2>Header 2</h2>
<p>This text uses normal (parenthesis)</p>
<p>This text uses ASCII &#40; parenthesis &#x29;. </p>
<p>This is a list of stuff in parethesis (one two three four) and it doesn't work.</p>
<p> This is some inline math $a = b+c$</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like parenthesis are set to be mathjax delimiters. Check the extension configuration if inline delimiters are well set to `$ $` (or better `$$ $$`) and not `$ $,( )`

extensions/plug-ins -> search for mathjax